# Update value of key in Object in nested array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nested-loops

I am trying to update data of "array1.array2._id": ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396af1") and Set Name to John But it's updating in all array2's first element's name to John.

```
db.getCollection('tests')
.updateOne({ "array1.array2._id": ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396af1") },{ $set: { "array1.$[].array2.$.name" : "John" } })

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396aec"),
    "array1" : [ 
        {
            "array2" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396af1"),
                    "name" : "test"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396af2"),
                    "name" : "ABC"
                }
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396aed")
        }, 
        {
            "array2" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396af3"),
                    "name" : "XYZ"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396af4"),
                    "name" : "Testing"
                }
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396aee")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update the value to the nested object array in mongodb document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72128886/how-to-update-the-value-to-the-nested-object-array-in-mongodb-document)

Comment: @nimrodserok No. In that answer they have "code": "Maroon" to check But we don't have _id : ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396aed"). We have only one _id ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396af1").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72128886/how-to-update-the-value-to-the-nested-object-array-in-mongodb-document/72131000#72131000) by @R2D2, you can do:

```
db.collection.update({
  "array1.array2._id": ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396af1")
},
{
  $set: {
    "array1.$[].array2.$[y].name": "John"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "y._id": ObjectId("627a6fab60dc3c523b396af1")
    }
  ]
})
```

As you can see on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ccb4ZPq1Pxp)